# Unable to locate Attribute with the given name [XXX] on this ManagedType [XXX] at PageRequest.of() properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) on an entity class, but why does the pageable function always auto convert into [lower camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)?

Because of that, I'm meet the error

> Unable to locate Attribute with the given name [messageSequenceID] on this ManagedType [com.loader.batch.IF.entity.UserFlight]

Here is my code:

In the UserFlight entity class is like this

```
package com.loader.batch.IF.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "data_flight")
public class UserFlight {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "MessageSequenceID", nullable = false)
    private Long MessageSequenceID;

    @Column(name = "MessageType", length = 30)
    private String MessageType;

    @Column(name = "ServiceType", length = 30)
    private String ServiceType;

    @Column(name = "OperationMode", length = 30)
    private String OperationMode;

    @Column(name = "SendDateTime", length = 30)
    private String SendDateTime;

    @Column(name = "CreateDateTime", length = 30)
    private String CreateDateTime;

    public UserFlight(
            Long MessageSequenceID,
            String MessageType,
            String ServiceType,
            String OperationMode, String SendDateTime, String CreateDateTime) {
        this.MessageSequenceID = MessageSequenceID;
        this.MessageType = MessageType;
        this.ServiceType = ServiceType;
        this.OperationMode = OperationMode;
        this.SendDateTime = SendDateTime;
        this.CreateDateTime = CreateDateTime;
    }

    public Long getMessageSequenceID() {
        return MessageSequenceID;
    }

    public void setMessageSequenceID(Long messageSequenceID) {
        MessageSequenceID = messageSequenceID;
    }

    public String getMessageType() {
        return MessageType;
    }

    public void setMessageType(String messageType) {
        MessageType = messageType;
    }

    public String getServiceType() {
        return ServiceType;
    }

    public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
        ServiceType = serviceType;
    }

    public String getOperationMode() {
        return OperationMode;
    }

    public void setOperationMode(String operationMode) {
        OperationMode = operationMode;
    }

    public String getSendDateTime() {
        return SendDateTime;
    }

    public void setSendDateTime(String sendDateTime) {
        SendDateTime = sendDateTime;
    }

    public String getCreateDateTime() {
        return CreateDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreateDateTime(String createDateTime) {
        CreateDateTime = createDateTime;
    }

}
```

And the service class is like this:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(req.getPage(), req.getLimit(), Sort.by("MessageSequenceID"));

UserFlight userFlight = new UserFlight();
userFlight.setStatus(req.getSearch());
Example<UserFlight> example = Example.of(userFlight, SEARCH_CONDITIONS_MATCH_ANY);

var flightData = flightRepository.findAll(example, pageable);
```

And exception appear because of pageable object doesn't find the attribute messageSequenceID:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute with the given name [messageSequenceID] on this ManagedType [com.loader.batch.IF.entity.UserFlight]
```

I'm already tried to add `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` on the application.properties, and change the Sort.by() parameter into messageSequenceID.

It doesn't work. It's still using messageSequenceID, not MessageSequenceID.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the type-safe API to define the sort expressions as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.paging-and-sorting).

For example, in your case:

```java
TypedSort<UserFlight> userFlightSort = Sort.sort(UserFlight.class);
Sort sort = userFlightSort.by(UserFlight::getMessageSequenceID)
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(req.getPage(), req.getLimit(), sort);

UserFlight userFlight = new UserFlight();
userFlight.setStatus(req.getSearch());
Example<UserFlight> example = Example.of(userFlight, SEARCH_CONDITIONS_MATCH_ANY);

var flightData = flightRepository.findAll(example, pageable);
```

I am not sure why the `Sort.by(String... properties)` cannot resolve the property name. It might have to do with the [Property expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions), because it is stated that the resolution algorithm checks for the property with that name (uncapitalized):

> The resolution algorithm starts by interpreting the entire part (AddressZipCode) as the property and checks the domain class for a property name as uncapitalized

But again, I am not sure that this logic applies to `Sort.by`.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution algorithm checks the domain class for a property with that name, but **uncapitalized**, so it searches for `messageSequenceID` instead of `MessageSequenceID`.

Follow the naming convention in Java and use variables that start with lowercase letters to avoid problems.

Use `messageSequenceID` instead of `MessageSequenceID` in your domain model.